# Excel vlookup-like command line function or tool?

Tags: macos, bash, replace, command-line, terminal

I have a source file that has 2M+ lines of text that look like this:

```
388708091|347|||||0010.60|N01/2012|
388708101|348|||||0011.60|N01/2012|
388708101|349|||||0012.60|N01/2012|
388719001|348|||||0010.38|M05/2013|
388719001|349|||||0011.38|M05/2013|
```

I would like to map and replace the second column (which has values like 347,348,349,etc.) with a map that looks like below:

```
346 309
347 311
348 312
349 313
350 314
351 315
352 316
```

Mind you, while the map is 2-D, there are over 100 rows.

What's the most efficient command-line way of replacing the data in the second column of the source file with the target map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` seems like the tool for the job:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$1] = $2; next } FNR == 1 { FS = "|"; OFS = FS; $0 = $0 } { $2 = a[$2] } 1' mapfile datafile
```

The code works as follows:

```
NR == FNR {       # while processing the first file (mapfile)
  a[$1] = $2      # remember the second field by the first
  next            # do nothing else
}
FNR == 1 {        # at the first line of the second file (datafile):
  FS  = "|"       # start splitting by | instead of whitespace
  OFS = FS        # delimit output the same way as the input
  $0  = $0        # force resplitting of this first line
}
{                 # for all lines in the second file:
  $2 = a[$2]      # replace the 2nd field with the remembered value for that key
}
1                 # print the line
```

**Caveat:** This assumes that every value in the second column of the data file has a corresponding entry in the map file; those that don't will be replaced with an empty string. If this behavior is not desirable, replace

```
{ $2 = a[$2] }
```

with

```
{ if($2 in a) { $2 = a[$2] } else { $2 = "something else" } }
```

It is not obvious to me what should happen in this case.